# Unable to retrieve token from Azure API

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get a token to be able to retrieve Groups information in Azure AD

This is my powershell script against the API:

```
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token?api-version=1.6'
    -Header @{'Content-type' = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
    -Body '{grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<clientID>&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default&client_secret=<clientSecret> }'
```

I keep getting this error:  `{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.\r\nTrace ID:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your body ia malformed, just do:

```
$body = @{
    Grant_Type    = 'client_credentials'
    Scope         = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
    Client_Id     = $ClientID
    Client_Secret = $Secret
}
$con = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantid/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method 'Post' -Body $body
$token = $con.access_token
```